# Laravel 5.5 validating hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

How can I create a validation on a hasMany relationship

That is my Product model

```
public function produtoAtributos(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\ProdutoAtributo", "produto_id", 'id')->latest();
}
```

and in Controller I fill the inputs than save it

```
$produtoatributos = $model->produtoAtributos()->getModel();

$produtoatributos->tipo = $produtoAtributo['tipo'];

$model->produtoAtributos()->save($produtoatributos);
```

The form input looks like this

```
<input name="ProdutoAtributos[0]['tipo']" />
```

How can add a validation for the relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel provide a nice way to validate arrays inpputs.

Here is an example

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'ProdutoAtributos.*.tipo' => 'required',
    ]);
```

You can read more about it here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays